# MFC application with dynamically created controls suddenly stops responding

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a MFC application (Visual Studio 2010) which dynamically creates and destroys lots of editboxes, drop-down boxes, and buttons, based on the user's consequent input.

I used "Create" function to dynamically create controls, and when deleting controls the system first calls "DestoryWindow" function for each control, and then delete each control pointer.

After iterating certain amount of creating/deleting controls, if I try to "open" the dropdown menu, the system fails to open it and stops responding to my input - but I can add more controls, if I do not try to open the dropdown menu.

Could somebody please let me know how to workaround this strange issue? This one nearly drives me crazy...

Comment: Maybe you have resource leak?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Workaround is simple - don't try to "open" that menu :)

Now I assume that you want to **FIX** the issue. Then you need to figure out what is going on. The system may be non-responsive for multiple reasons, most likely one of these two:

- You are in a busy loop in your main UI thread.
- You are waiting for an event that never happens. Deadlock, for example.

When your application is frozen, try to attach debugger to it and do Debug -> Break All. Then see what code is executing. If the reason for this "freeze" will not be obvious, please post relevant code.